# SQLite3 сам заменяет значения на NULL

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

В общем у меня есть дискорд-бот, и у него есть БД, в которой хранится: айди_юзера, кастомный_статус, количество_коинов. И когда я заменяю например только айди_юзера и кастомный_статус, то количество_коинов заменяется на NULL, и наоборот, если заменяю айди_юзера и количество_коинов, то статус меняется на NULL.
С коинами проблема такая: я сделал, чтобы по дефолту стоял ноль, и если у человека было сколько-то, то сбрасывается в 0
Вот скриншот базы данных:
[image: БД]

Код:

```
БД:
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "user_id"   INTEGER UNIQUE,
    "status"    TEXT,
    "coins" INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);
Вставка данных (на примере статуса)
db_conn.cursor().execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users (user_id, status) VALUES (?, ?)", (ctx.author.id,new_status))
```

Comment: Используйте `UPDATE`, а не `INSERT OR REPLACE`

Comment: Спасибо большое, но уже успел найти данный способ и использовать))

Comment: Если вы пишите "Решено", у вас должно быть отображено решение.